# Python3: Access an object's parent class property

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties

I'm trying to access an object's parent class "getter" property and pass it as a function argument. The problem is it is passing the value from the "getter" and not the getter function itself. I would like to be able to pass this function into another class and get the updated value each call.

For example, if the value returned by the getter function is 77 when it is passed, the value 77 is passed and not the function itself. The goal is to pass the function that returns the current value and not the value when first passed.

I tried looking for the property in the object's `__dict__`, but it only shows the methods,etc for the child class and not the base class. I tried using super as a way to access this but couldn't figure out if that was the correct path.

```py
################### Class definitions from library ###################
# The parent class from the library
class Adafruit_BME280():
     # ... Removed Code ...
     @property
     def temperature(self):
          self._read_temperature()
          return self._t_fine / 5120.0

# The child class from the library
class Adafruit_BME280_I2C(Adafruit_BME280):
     # ... Removed Code ...

################### My Code ###################
# My new class that is passed a function to get temperature
class TempSensor:
     def __init__(self, get_temperature_func):
          self.get_temperature = get_temperature_func

     def print_temperature():
          print(self.get_temperature)

# My main function where the object is created
def main():
     bme280 = Adafruit_BME280_I2C()
     temp_sensor = TempSensor(bme280.temperature)
     temp_sensor.print_temperature
#
```

In the code given above, if the temperature when the TempSensor object is 77.0 degrees when it is created then temp_sensor.print_temperature always prints 77.0 when called instead of the current temperature.

Comment: did you consider using a normal method instead of a property? Seems to fit your problem better

Comment: It's one of Adafruit's libraries that I was hoping to not modify. Their usage seems a bit strange because there is no "setter" part of the property so seems like they should have used a normal method